# aid + to infinitive vs. aid + to gerund

Tags: word-usage, difference

Is there any subtle difference in meaning between them? For example in the two following sentences:

- The computer is an aid to keeping costs down.
- The computer is an aid to keep costs down.

I think the former is preferred, but the latter is also possible.

Comment: They would both be understood but the second suggests that the computer is an aid, and its job is to keep costs down. Please prefer the first!